# Is it possible to run 2 separate instances for CRM pointing to same sql server?

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server-2008, c#-4.0, crm

Currently I am running Dynamics CRM 4, Is it possible to run two instances of CRM pointing to the same data base? Assuming these 2 instances of CRM are running on the different servers.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would say its probably a bad idea. I'm not sure what Dynamics CRM is capable of in terms of scaling, it *might* work, but most likely they'll clash. If you can control the name of the DB, they can certainly co-exist in different databases on the same SQL Server Machine.

Answer (score 0):

If you want network balancing, you can do it at well.

[Install Microsoft Dynamics CRM 4.0 Server on multiple computers](http://rc.crm.dynamics.com/rc/regcont/en_us/op/articles/crm_server_nlb.aspx#ID0ESF)